# Is it possible to fetch data from any site in Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I am new to Chrome App development. I was going to create a simple RSS reader as a helloworld project, but now, after reading docs, I am not sure that this is possible. The problem is, by the Content Security Policy for Chrome Apps it is forbidden to use domain in url_handlers without proving that this is your domain.
It makes retrieving RSS from sites impossible.

But there are references to some sandbox technology in the docs, and Chrome Apps can use low-level sockets. Can I somehow use it to get RSS from any site?

Comment: Oh, if the question itself is bad by format or something, please comment to help me improve it.

Comment: I think your question is fine; it just shows you don't understand how apps work. For a beginner, this is a question that shows attempts at research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer because its topic is so broad.

But to answer if it's possible. **Yes** it is possible. You'll see that there are already RSS reader applications out there, go and check the webstore and even "reverse engineer" them to study it up if you want.
I also did some RSS reader for a few clients before.

I hope I can give you sample codes to you now but its better if you start looking into main documentation and sample apps.

You should read on XHR to access pages
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

You may encounter a lot issues in tackling this project.

1. You need to consider that websites may load slow and your app should provide some UI for loading and some timeout to give up after a few seconds.
2. Webpages will redirect, so you should handle if you are going to follow it or not
3. Sometimes link is 404, or sometimes its not XML
4. You need to cache things, you may need servers help for this

It's a tough project to do but don't get discouraged.

It is still a fun and challenging one and you should **go for it** still!

Have fun coding!